# proftpd server allow second or multiple public key for single user

Tags: authentication, public-key, proftpd

If I'm using openssh server, allowing multiple public keys are simple. It is enough put it into file ~/.ssh/authorized_keys   with content

```
ssh-rsa ****there_is_public_ssh_key****  some_text_typically_user@host
ssh-rsa  *****second_pub_key****  another_text
...
```

But how to do it with proftpd with sftp protocol?
Typical configuration for single public key is, base config for virtual or global:

```
SFTPAuthorizedUserKeys file:/some_key_ssl_store/%u/autorized_keys
```

with example autorized_keys file content:

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "some comment"
*****public_key_splitted_with_some_lines*****
****second line for the same key ******
****third line*****
****as many lines as is needed *****
***last_line***==
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

How could I store second key? Should I insert next block BEGIN to END after this example? Unfortunately I didn't find clear explanation for this one.

Currently I'm using workaround with many users with the same UID's , but this is not so clear config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to separate each key with `----BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY-----` and `-----END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY-----` lines.  Those markers are how parsers of that file know when a given key starts/ends.

Thus, for example:

```
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "4096-bit RSA, converted from OpenSSH by castaglia"
AAAAB3Nza...
...
1e1YNo9hYjE=
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "2048-bit RSA, converted from OpenSSH by castaglia"
AAAAB3Nza..
...
Byq2pv4VBo953gK7f1AQ==
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
```

Hope this helps!